# How to safely login to other site via cURL on server?

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have an account on some hosting server (PHP + MySQL). I know that I should trust it but...

My script checker.php login to www.ebok.pl via cURL. On www.ebok.pl I have many private data. checker.php gets some data from www.ebok.pl every 5 minutes by CRON (link to checker.php). I keep login and password to www.ebok.pl as regular text in database, and cookie file in COOKIE folder outside public_html.

Is there any other safety option to login to another page. Maybe somehow hash a password or cookie file?

Comment: It's useless to hash the password because you need the plain text either way to login. If you are running something on server X server X will have all the info period.